# Is it possible to deliver SIGINT to a blocking recv system call in C?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, signals, system-calls

I'm in a situation where receive (`recv()`) timeout varies at different places. So i decided to implement custom receive timeout feature. Before calling recv(), I would place a `alarm(timeout)` and register for `SIGALRM`, and when `SIGALRM` is delivered to process it would `raise(SIGINT)` from signal handler. When `SIGINT` is delivered to process, I would expect the `recv()` to be interrupted and set `errno` as `EINTR`. Is this is the right way to do it?

Comment: No. Register your handler for `SIGALRM` with `sigaction()` *without* `SA_RESTART` in its `sa_flags` and it will interrupt the blocking `recv()`. No need to raise another signal.

Comment: But better don't use blocking i/o -- make the socket non-blocking, and `select()` or `poll()` with a timeout on it. (On most Unix systems you don't even have to make it non-blocking -- you can simply use `recv(..., MSG_DONTWAIT)`.)